# NMaximize with matrix input

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, contexts

I defined function `f[x_, fixed_] := {...}`. Here `x` is an $M\times N$ matrix. I want to maximize $f$ with respect to $x$. I have three questions:

1. By default, `NMaximize` treats all variables as real. How can I inform *Mathematica* that $x$ here is a real matrix?
2. I tried `FindMaximum`, by typing `FindMaximum[f[x, fixed],{x}]`, with `x` as a matrix. The weird thing is that in the process of `FindMaximum`, my function `f` did not evaluate `x`; it just kept `x` as a variable name without content. How to understand and fix this thing? BTW, my function `f` is not in the global context but in a private context.
3. Indeed, the function $f$ here is an approximate of its theoretical counterpart $f_0$. And I know $f_0(x)$ is maximized when $x\in A$. Here $A$ is a subset in Euclid space. My actual aim is to approximate the set $A$. Let $x^*$ be the $\arg\max$ of $f$ found by `Mathematica` somehow. Intuitively, I want to keep all $x'$ such that $|f(x')-f(x^*)|<\epsilon$ for a chosen $\epsilon$. How can I achieve this goal? I noticed that `NMaximize` has a option called `StepMonitor`, which might help.

Comment: A simple but brutal way is to use the explicit matrix elements as the arguments in `FindMaximum`. Something like `FindMaximum[f[{{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}}, fixed],{x11, x12, x21, x22}]`.

Comment: Look at the post `Using FindMinimum with matrix input`. It's on a similar topic.